# `MongoError: not authorized` for a call to ensureIndex without requiring auth

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm accessing a mongo instance that has no users set up, and is not requiring auth. And yet, when I run `myDb.myCollection.ensureIndex({username:1}, {unique: true})`, I get the following error:

`MongoError: not authorized on myDb to execute command { listIndexes: "User", cursor: {} }`

Its strange to me that it errors with a 'listIndexes' call when I'm calling ensureIndex.

I'm using mongoskin for db access, mongo 3.0.0, and node 5.1.0

Comment: I think this was being caused by me using the old format for mongo config